# Parsing API Response (object) from component to another component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms, angular4-httpclient

I want to parse API response to another component

This is code from 'detail_item.component.ts', this code sent data to route "bookitem" in 'book_item.component.ts'

```
onSubmit(){
    this.appService.addItem(this.item).subscribe(item => {
      if(item.status ==200){
        this.router.navigate(['/bookitem'], {queryParams: {data: item.data}});
      }
    })
}
```

this is code from 'book_item.component.ts'

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.routeActive.queryParams.filter(params => params.data).subscribe(params => {
       this.book_item = params.data;
    });
}
```

when I `console.log(this.book_item)`, what I got from it is [object object]. It should be contain json data.

Comment: add https://stackblitz.com/ example or more information about response you get

Comment: by just looking at the code you have - it looks like you item.data is an object, not primitive object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type of item.data is object you need to convert it to string first which is like

```
onSubmit(){
    this.appService.addItem(this.item).subscribe(item => {
      if(item.status ==200){
        this.router.navigate(['/bookitem'], {queryParams: {data: 
JSON.stringify(item.data)}});
      }
    })
}
```

then you can parse it when you read it from the route on the other component

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.book_item = JSON.parse(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['data']);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got `[object object]` that is completely fine due to you are trying to pass object in query string. Further more you can't pass object in query string you can pass value that is convertible to string easily like number.